# how to change height of gridView on the basis of item index ?? [ FLUTTER ]

Tags: user-interface, flutter, gridview, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

This is the UI... I am trying to create using gridView

[image]

If you have any other option then kindly tell me how I can create this in flutter

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view try it.

Comment: Thanks.... ti worked but is there any way to do this without using any 3rd party package ??